# In a Winforms Chart, how to change the drawing parameters for a Point according to its underlying data?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, charts

I am using the .NET Windows Forms [Microsoft Chart Component](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart).

My data objects would look like more evolved versions of the following class:

```
class DataObject {
    public double ValueX {get;}
    public double ValueY {get;}
    public boolean IsRed {get;} 
}
```

I have been able to bind my chart to my data by setting the `Chart.dataSource` property to an `ICollection` of `DataObject`. I have also been able to configure a `Series` that has X = `valueX` and Y = `valueY`.

Now I want to (for example) give a special color to the points in the series depending on the value of `IsRed`.

What would be the best way to achieve that in Visual Studio 2008/2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't make sense to continue databinding when the need is so complex - so I simply put the points in the chart by using the `addPoint` methods.

That way I can change each point's formatting as I wish.